# How to decode DNSServiceQueryRecord requests for debugging purposes?

Tags: macos, dns

I am currently trying to debug an undesired 30s delay in an [application](https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/2375) that is caused by some DNS queries which I was able to stop inside the Console.app. The problem is that what is logged is almost useless and only a mask.hash is logged and not the real query.

```
default 08:08:07.717039+0000    mDNSResponder   [R1351382] DNSServiceCreateConnection START PID[53961](python3.10)
default 08:08:07.717132+0000    mDNSResponder   [R1351383] DNSServiceQueryRecord(1D000, 0, <mask.hash: 'W4U2JyNMP4qPLaREUfA9Aw=='>, Addr) START PID[53961](python3.10)
default 08:08:07.717885+0000    mDNSResponder   [R1351384] DNSServiceQueryRecord(1D000, 0, <mask.hash: 'W4U2JyNMP4qPLaREUfA9Aw=='>, AAAA) START PID[53961](python3.10)
default 08:08:07.718398+0000    mDNSResponder   [R1351383] DNSServiceQueryRecord(1D000, 0, <mask.hash: 'AxiCO2kN2tb6f+xUNi2KVQ=='>, Addr) STOP PID[53961](python3.10)
default 08:08:07.718460+0000    mDNSResponder   [R1351384] DNSServiceQueryRecord(1D000, 0, <mask.hash: 'AxiCO2kN2tb6f+xUNi2KVQ=='>, AAAA) STOP PID[53961](python3.10)
default 08:08:07.719293+0000    mDNSResponder   [R1351385] DNSServiceQueryRecord(15000, 0, <mask.hash: 'BbGOo0pN8UoXPv6jtlO7tg=='>, PTR) START PID[53961](python3.10)
default 08:08:37.720264+0000    mDNSResponder   [R1351385] DNSServiceQueryRecord(15000, 0, <mask.hash: 'lubOf0RtXl5C9ERWs7ZGfQ=='>, PTR) STOP PID[53961](python3.10)
default 08:08:37.745626+0000    mDNSResponder   [R1351382] DNSServiceCreateConnection STOP PID[53961](python3.10)
```

How can I identify the real queries?

Answer (score 1):

Sorted by installing the profile from https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/sierra-console-private/ -- or you can try to build your own.

Comment: I have the same issue as the poster and this doesn't resolve it. That profile reveals many private log values, but DNS query logs still show `mask.hash: .... `. It seems in the latest version of macOS certain things, like domains, are stilled protected in the logs even when private logging is enabled.